# Rails: How to use RegExp in RESTful routes instead of hard-coded controller names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

By default Rails offer two ways to set your RESTful routes (let `:id` segment is an integer constraint `/[0-9]/+`):

```
 1. site.com/users/10/homes/15
 2. site.com/user/homes/15
```

**The first variant:**

Your controllers: `UsersController` and `HomesController`

Your routes:

```
resources(:users) do  #=> plural, so the url path is /users/10, :id segment possible
    resources(:homes) #=> plural, so the url path is /homes/10, :id segment possible
end
```

**The second variant:**

Your controllers: `UsersController` and `HomesController`

Your routes:

```
resource(:user) do    #=> singular, so the url path is /user, no :id segment
    resources(:homes) #=> plural, so the url path is /homes/10, :id segment possible
end
```

But these URLs do not look nice. I want them to be like this one:

```
site.com/bugsbunny123/homeinny
```

The first and the second segments are a regexp but are still connected to `Users` and `Homes` controllers and are RESTful. I know how to achieve it using Non-Resourceful Routes. But then it’s quite tedious to map each one to controller’s RESTful methods using `:via => POST`, `:via => PUT`, `:except` etc.

I want something like this:

```
:users => /[A-Za-z0-9]+/
resource(:users) do ...
```

or like this:

```
resource(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/ => :users) do ...
```

The idea is to use the regexp user name instead of hard-coded `/users/10` that the default RESTful router offers now.

Is it possible to implement it still using `resource(:controller)`?  Or I do have to use Non-Resourceful Routes?

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong framework. Rails is cool because of it's RESTful routing

Comment: the `resource` macro is just a macro of bundled urls... if you don't want those url styles then you should write them explicitly